# C++ String Value Control

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I want to control my value with regex.

Example:

string value1 = "{1N851111-8M32-2234-B83K-123456789012}"; //Good

Regex:

```
std::regex control("^[{]{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{12}[A-Za-z0-9]$[}]");
```

**Source-Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::string code1 = "{1N851111-8M32-2234-B83K-123456789012}";
    std::regex control("^[{]{8}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{4}[A-Za-z0-9]{1}[-]{12}[A-Za-z0-9]$[}]");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(code1, match, control))
    {
        std::cout << "MAtch found";

    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Match not found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My Output:**

```
Match not found
```

Comment: "control this structur"??? It's not even remotely clear what you are asking here.

Comment: I always want to have this value structure ({1N851111-8M32-2234-B83K-123456789012}). I want to know. how can build a value control with this structure to get always this value.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any questions about regexs?

Comment: Plenty of online tutorials for regex, like this: http://regexone.com/  Also, is this anything to do with Lightswitch or UI Automation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671293(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. `

Comment: Sorry for my bad description case. I update know my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex declaration to

```
std::regex control("^[{][A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}[}]$");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fT2pX2/1) and the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/v1haRz)

You misused the limiting quantifiers. Look:

- `[{]{8}` - matches 8 `{` symbols
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{1}` - matches 1 letter or digit
- `[-]{4}` - matches 4 hyphens, etc.

Also, you set `$` end-of-string anchor before the last `}`, so, the pattern was looking for a `}` after the end of the string, which failed the match automatically.